# Execute immediate use in select * from in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to get maximum length of column data in oracle by executing a dynamic query as part of Select statement , except seems i don't think we can use `execute immediate` in an select clause. Could i get some help with syntax or understanding as to better way to do this.

```
SELECT
        owner OWNER,
        table_name,
        column_name,
        'select max(length('||column_name||')) from '||table_name||';' max_data_length
FROM
    dba_tab_columns
WHERE
    AND ( data_type = 'NUMBER'
          OR data_type = 'INTEGER' )
```

the 4th column in above query spits out a sql string rather than computing the value and returning it.

Comment: You can only use dynamic SQL in PL/SQL, not in a plain (static) SQL statement. But even besides that - what do you mean by length of a **number**? "Length" is defined for strings, not for numbers. A small example of what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you are looking for.  My guess is that you want a PL/SQL block where you iterate through `dba_tab_columns` and issue subsequent statements.

Comment: @mathguy I would like to get precision of integer and number columns in oracle. Seems most of our tables don't have them. so computing them from the max value would be the only way. example; PersonId column has max value of 2500 then our max precision would be 4

Comment: OK - but then you would need scale too? Also, do you expect that all the "number" columns are in fact "non-negative integer"? In a price column, you may have the price 8.33, the precision is 3 but the length is 4 (because the decimal period is included in the "length" count).

Comment: Just curious, too - why do you think it is important to limit the precision of integer columns? Most columns don't have the precision specified. Understood. Why is that important? Perhaps you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist - or perhaps it is a real problem, with a much simpler solution.

Comment: The size and precision of number columns are already in dba_tab_columns. The data itself cannot give you these values, because it may not fill the column.

Comment: @AlistairWall - Only if they were defined. The OP said they weren't, and he is considering getting that info from the data and then entering it in the catalog (redefining the columns).

Comment: just to give in context, i am in process of migrating our oracle databases to postgres aurora. if you read more in this article, they would mention why this needs to be done https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/convert-the-number-data-type-from-oracle-to-postgresql-part-1/

Comment: OK - so you will need to look at the length of numbers, after you discard decimal point and potentially minus sign. Next question though - what will you do with columns that are defined with negative scale? For example `number(4, -2)`. Or are you 100% sure such oddities are not present in your db? 12300 has precision 3 and scale -2; 12345 has precision 5 and scale 0, and if you store it in a `number(4, -2)` column it will be rounded to, and stored as, 12300. What if you decide that 12300 is `number(5,0)` even though the column is already explicitly `number(4, -2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some food for thought. Note that I am only looking for numeric columns that don't already have precision specified in the catalog. (If you prefer, you can audit **all** numeric columns and compare the declared precision against the actual precision used by your data.)

I am also looking only in specific schemas. Instead, you may give a list of schemas to be ignored; I hope you are not seriously considering making any changes to `SYS`, for example, even if it does (and it does!) have numeric columns without specified precision.

The catalog doesn't store `INTEGER` in the data type; instead, it stores that as `NUMBER(38)` So I am not searching for data type `INTEGER` in `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`. But this raises an interesting question - perhaps you should search for all columns where `DATA_PRECISION` is `null` (as in my code below), but also for `DATA_PRECISION = 38`.

In the code below I use `DBMS_OUTPUT` to display the findings directly to the screen. You will probably want to do something smarter with this; either create a table function, or create a table and insert the findings in it, or perhaps even issue DDL already (note that those also require dynamic SQL).

This still leaves you to deal with scale. Perhaps you can get around that with a specification like `NUMBER(prec, *)` - not sure if that will meet your needs. But the idea is similar; you will just need to write code carefully, like I did for precision (accounting for the decimal point and the minus sign, for example).

Long story short, here is what I ran on my system, and the output it produced.

```
declare
  prec number;
begin
  for rec in (
    select owner, table_name, column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  owner in ('SCOTT', 'HR')
      and  data_type = 'NUMBER'
      and  data_precision is null
  )
  loop
    execute immediate
      'select max(length(translate(to_char(' || rec.column_name ||
              '), ''0-.'', ''0'')))
              from ' || rec.owner || '.' || rec.table_name
       into   prec;
    dbms_output.put_line('owner: '        || lpad(rec.owner, 12, ' ')       ||
                         ' table name: '  || lpad(rec.table_name, 12, ' ')  ||
                         ' column_name: ' || lpad(rec.column_name, 12, ' ') ||
                         ' precision: '   || prec);
  end loop;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

owner:           HR table name:      REGIONS column_name:    REGION_ID precision: 1
owner:           HR table name:    COUNTRIES column_name:    REGION_ID precision: 1
owner:        SCOTT table name:     SALGRADE column_name:        GRADE precision: 1
owner:        SCOTT table name:     SALGRADE column_name:        LOSAL precision: 4
owner:        SCOTT table name:     SALGRADE column_name:        HISAL precision: 4


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**EDIT**

Here are several additional points (mostly, corrections) based on extended conversations with Sayan Malakshinov in comments to my answer and to his.

Most importantly, even if we can figure out max precision of numeric columns, that doesn't seem directly related to the ultimate goal of this whole thing, which is to determine the correct Postgre data types for the existing Oracle columns. For example in Postgre, unlike Oracle, it is important to distinguish between integer and non-integer. Unless scale is explicitly 0 in Oracle, we don't know that the column is "integers only"; we could find that out, through a similar dynamic SQL approach, but we would be checking for non-integer values, not precision.

Various corrections: My query is careless with regard to quoted identifiers (schema name, table name, column name). See the proper use of double-quotes in the dynamic query in Sayan's answer; my dynamic query should be modified to use double-quotes in the same way his does.

In my approach I pass numbers through `TO_CHAR` and then remove minus sign and decimal period. Of course, one's system may use comma, or other symbols, for decimal separator; the safer approach is to remove everything that is not a digit. That can be done with

```
translate(col_name, '0123456789' || col_name, '0123456789')
```

The query also doesn't handle very large or very small numbers, which **can** be stored in the Oracle database, but can only be represented in scientific notation when passed through `TO_CHAR()`.

In any case, since "max precision" doesn't seem directly related to the ultimate goal of mapping to correct data types in Postgre, I am not changing the code - leaving it in the original form.

Thanks to Sayan for pointing out all these issues.

One more thing - `*_TAB_COLUMNS` contains information about view columns too; very likely those should be ignored for the task at hand. Very easy to do, as long as we realize it needs to be done.

Comment: length(to_char()) with format model is not about binary integers either... You are operating  decimal representations, so your comment to my answer is related to your one too. Moreover I would never suggest to use to_char without exact format model - that is just a NLS-bomb.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - are you confusing `to_char` as applied to numbers, vs. `to_char` as applied to dates? What NLS bomb for `to_char(number)`? I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xtender/eea7e4e74f5527e4678186b18aa91e0b

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - I see - at the very least, the decimal character may be comma, not period. Regarding scientific notation, I already pointed out to the OP a related issue: numbers like 12300 may be stored in `number(3, -2)`; precision is not directly related to the magnitude of integers, unlike length, which is related to magnitude.

Comment: Thanks God! At least you agreed with one point. But still trying to say that you don't understand vsize and still talking about lengths of numbers...

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - I edited my reply to reference all these observations; see if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

Reading carefully that AWS article and since both previous answers (including mine) use  rough estimate (length+to_char without format model and vsize operate decimal length, not bytes), I decided to write another full answer.

Look at this simple example:

```
with 
function f_bin(x number) return varchar2 as
  bi binary_integer;
  e_overflow exception;
  pragma exception_init(e_overflow, -1426);
begin
  bi:=x;
  return case when bi=x then 'ok' else 'error' end;
exception when e_overflow then return 'error';
end;

function f_check(x number, f varchar2) return varchar2 as
begin
  return case when to_number(to_char(abs(x),f),f) = abs(x) then 'ok' else 'error' end;
exception when VALUE_ERROR then return 'error';
end;

a(a1) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(
    1,
    0.1,
    -0.1,
    -7,
    power(2,15)-1,
    power(2,16)-1,
    power(2,31)-1,
    power(2,32)-1
  ))
)
select 
  a1,
  f_check(a1,'fm0XXX') byte2,
  f_check(a1,'fm0XXXXXXX') byte4,
  f_bin(a1) ff_signed_binary_int,
  to_char(abs(a1),'fm0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') f_byte8,
  f_check(a1,'fm0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') byte8,
  vsize(a1) vs,
  dump(a1) dmp
from a;
```

Result:

```
        A1 BYTE2      BYTE4      FF_SIGNED_ F_BYTE8          BYTE8              VS DMP
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 ok         ok         ok         0000000000000001 ok                  2 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
        .1 error      error      error      0000000000000000 error               2 Typ=2 Len=2: 192,11
       -.1 error      error      error      0000000000000000 error               3 Typ=2 Len=3: 63,91,102
        -7 ok         ok         ok         0000000000000007 ok                  3 Typ=2 Len=3: 62,94,102
     32767 ok         ok         ok         0000000000007FFF ok                  4 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,4,28,68
     65535 ok         ok         ok         000000000000FFFF ok                  4 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,7,56,36
2147483647 error      ok         ok         000000007FFFFFFF ok                  6 Typ=2 Len=6: 197,22,48,49,37,48
4294967295 error      ok         error      00000000FFFFFFFF ok                  6 Typ=2 Len=6: 197,43,95,97,73,96
```

Here I used PL/SQL functions for readability and to make it more clear.

Function f_bin casts an input number parameter to PL/SQL binary_integer (signed int4) and compares the result with input parameter, ie it checks if it loses accuracy. Defined exception shows that it can raise an exception 1426 "numeric overflow".

Function f_check does double conversion to_number(to_char(...)) of the input value and checks if it's still equal to the input value. Here I use hexadecimal format mask (XX = 1 byte), so it checks if an input number can fit an in this format mask. Hexadecimal format model works with non-negative numbers, so we need to use abs() here.

F_BYTE8 shows formatted value that uses a function from the column BYTE8, so you can easily see the loss of accuracy here.

All the above were just for readability, but we can make the same using just pure SQL:

```
with 
a(a1) as (
  select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(
    1,
    0.1,
    -0.1,
    -7,
    power(2,15)-1,
    power(2,16)-1,
    power(2,31)-1,
    power(2,32)-1
  ))
)
select 
  a1,
  case when abs(a1) = to_number(to_char(abs(a1),'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') default null on conversion error,'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
       then ceil(length(to_char(abs(a1),'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'))/2)
       else -1
  end xx,
  vsize(a1) vs,
  dump(a1) dmp
from a;
```

Result:

```
        A1         XX         VS DMP
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------
         1          1          2 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
        .1         -1          2 Typ=2 Len=2: 192,11
       -.1         -1          3 Typ=2 Len=3: 63,91,102
        -7          1          3 Typ=2 Len=3: 62,94,102
     32767          2          4 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,4,28,68
     65535          2          4 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,7,56,36
2147483647          4          6 Typ=2 Len=6: 197,22,48,49,37,48
4294967295          4          6 Typ=2 Len=6: 197,43,95,97,73,96
```

As you can see, here I return -1 in case of conversion errors to byte8 and number of non-zero bytes otherwize.

Obviusly it can be simplified even more: you can just check range limits and that x=trunc(x) or mod(x,1)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is what you need:

VSIZE returns the number of bytes in the internal representation of expr. If expr is null, then this function returns null.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VSIZE.html

In Oracle INTEGER is just a number(*,0): http://orasql.org/2012/11/10/differences-between-integerint-in-sql-and-plsql/

```sql
select
 owner,table_name,column_name,
 data_type,data_length,data_precision,data_scale,avg_col_len
 ,x.vs
from (select/*+ no_merge */ c.*
      from dba_tab_columns c
        where data_type='NUMBER'
        and owner not in (select username from dba_users where ORACLE_MAINTAINED='Y')
      ) c
    ,xmltable(
       '/ROWSET/ROW/VSIZE'
       passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select nvl(max(vsize("'||c.column_name||'")),0) as VSIZE from "'||c.owner||'"."'||c.table_name||'"')
       columns vs int path '.'
    ) x
;
```

Update: if you read oracle internal number format (exponent+bcd-mantissa and look at a result of dump(x) function, you can see that Oracle stores numbers as a decimal value(4 bits per 1 decimal digit, 2 digits in 1 byte), so for such small ranges you can just take their maximum BCD mantissa+1 exponent as a rough estimation.

Comment: How is `vsize` related to the OP's question? I don't see it. `2^31 - 1` is a ten-digit decimal integer. It can be stored as a (signed or unsigned) 4-byte binary integer. The Oracle internal representation takes 6 bytes, which is what `vsize` reports; but the OP is investigating this for migration to Postgre, which does not use the internal representation Oracle does. I see no connection between `vsize` (and, also, average column length) and the OP's question. If there is one, it would be helpful to explain what it is - in your answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @mathguy oracle internal number format is pretty simple: just check dump() - it contains exponent and BCD mantissa - ie mantissa is means digits - exact the same you are calculating using length(to_char()) removing minus and dot signs

Comment: I know exactly how Oracle stores numbers internally. I don't see how that makes `vsize` relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @mathguy please read my comments and and update above carefully. Do you see any connection the number of digits in to_char() you are calculating above and OP's question?

Comment: I do see a direct connection between my answer and the OP's question. (Perhaps his question is not a good one given how he plans to use it). He asked about maximum precision of actual data in his tables. That is what I answered. Even deeper though, his question was more general - about the correct use of dynamic SQL. I showed him how to do that in PL/SQL; that is a general (and very basic) concept, illustrated on his immediate question about "precision" but with much greater applicability.

Comment: He can use the same to find the max absolute value in every numeric column, or whether there are non-integer values in such a column, etc. (Of course, he could use the XML trick instead - but that is at least one order of magnitude slower than the PL/SQL approach. In my tests, 500 ms vs. 20 ms.)

Comment: What I really see is that you always try to point out the speck in mine eye... Your answer doesn't answer how to use dynamic sql in select, nor answers about convertation to smallint/int/bigint in Postgre, nor shows how to get maximum precision, nor shows correct calculations...